# Looking to iterate through list of lists that skips over specific indices

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I'm currently working on a Python 3 project that involves iterating several times through a list of lists, and I want to write a code that skips over specific indices of this list of lists.  The specific indices are stored in a separate list of lists.  I have written a small list of lists, `grid` and the values I do not want to iterate over, `coordinates`:

```
grid = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
coordinates = [[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
```

Basically, I wish to skip over each 1 in  `grid`(the 1s are just used to make the corresponding coordinate locations more visible).

I tried the following code to no avail:

```py
for row in grid:
    for value in row:
        for coordinate in coordinates:
            if coordinate[0] != grid.index(row) and coordinate[1] != row.index(value):
                row[value] += 4
   
print(grid)
```

The expected output is: `[[4, 4, 1], [4, 1, 4], [1, 4, 4]]`

After executing the code with, I am greeted with `ValueError: 1 is not in list`.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why am I being given this error message when each `coordinate` in `coordinates` contains a 0th and 1st position?
2. Is there a better way to solve this problem than using for loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. The `row` contains a list of integers, and `value` contains values in those rows. The issue is that you need access to the *indices* of these values, not the values themselves. The way that you've set up your loops don't allow for that.
2. `.index()` returns the index of the first instance of the argument passed in; it is *not* a drop-in replacement for using indexing with brackets.

Here is a code snippet that does what you've described, fixing both of the above issues:

```py
grid = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
coordinates = [[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
for row in range(len(grid)):
    for col in range(len(grid[row])):
        if [row, col] not in coordinates:
            grid[row][col] += 4
   
print(grid)  # -> [[4, 4, 1], [4, 1, 4], [1, 4, 4]]
```

By the way, if you have a lot of coordinates, you can make it a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) of tuples rather than a 2D list so you don't have to iterate over the entire list for each row / column index pair. The set would look like `coordinates = {(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)}`, and you'd use `if (row, col) not in coordinates:` as opposed to `if [row, col] not in coordinates:` if you were using a set instead.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The code doesn't take into account the **coordinates telling which values in the grid to add 4 to regardless of whether it is a one or not**.

Comment: To me, it seemed like OP cared primarily about the coordinates rather than the actual value -- the coordinates in the list just happened to all contain 1.

Comment: This is wonderful and works perfectly, thank you so much!  I'm dealing with 5 unique coordinates so I don't think it'll be too much of an issue, although I am curious; how should it look if I were to use a set of tuples instead of a list of lists for the coordinates?

Comment: Edited into the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Here is a numpy way to do this, for anyone looking -

```
import numpy as np

g = np.array(grid)
c = np.array(coordinates)

mask = np.ones(g.shape, bool)
mask[tuple(c.T)] = False

#This mask skips each coordinate in the list
g[mask]+=4

print(g)
```

```
[[4 4 1]
 [4 1 4]
 [1 4 4]]
```

#### And a one-liner list comprehension, for those who prefer that -

```
[[j+4 if [row,col] not in coordinates else j for col,j in enumerate(i)] for row,i in enumerate(grid)]
```

```
[[4, 4, 1], [4, 1, 4], [1, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grid = [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0]]
coordinates = [[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]

for y, row in enumerate(grid):
    for x, value in enumerate(row):
        if [x, y] in coordinates or value != 1:
            grid[y][x] += 4
   
print(grid)
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's first question?

Comment: It might be cleaner to use the enumerated values: `row[x] = value + 4` instead of `grid[y][x] += 4`

Comment: This code answers both questions